# Why I receive this problem with xamarin forms and tizen?

Tags: c#, xamarin, tizen

I have a problem with VS Community 19 and Tizen.
I have created the hello world app but when I start the debug it gives me:

> Error while trying to enter break state. Debugging will now stop. Failed to find thread SomeNumber for break event.

I haven't set up any breakpoint!
In the output console I have this:

> Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.1.4/System.Private.CoreLib.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
>
> Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.1.4/SOS.NETCore.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
> Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.1.4/System.Runtime.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
> Loaded '/proc/4415/fd/17/bin/STVXamarinApplication1.Tizen.TV.dll'. Symbols loaded.

I have no idea what is the problem!

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/MIEngine/wiki/Logging

Comment: Check the requirement of VS with Tizen. https://developer.tizen.org/development/visual-studio-tools-tizen/installing-visual-studio-tools-tizen And provide the details about how to reproduce would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try this?

1. Solution Explorer - Neget Package Management (?)

   - Update Tab -> Update old libraries to use latest
2. Change code in the Main() method

global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Tizen.Forms.Init(app);

=>
**Forms.Init(app);**

Add **using Xamarin.Forms;**